# which is better to utilize AMQP, MQTT or TCP for ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, mqtt, spring-amqp

We are trying to utilize ActiveMQ. The confusion of which protocol is better to utilize for having application  usage with ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AMQP is an application-level standard for Message Oriented Middleware (MOM). JMS is a standard API for Java for communicating with MOM.

Two different Java applications using JMS could be using different MOM and hence still be unable to communicate. ActiveMQ is a MOM system with a JMS library that allows Java programs to access it using JMS, but it can't necessarily communicate with another JMS Java program using, say, WebLogic MOM.

Different AMQP MOM systems can interoperate with each other (assuming that they are using the same version of AMQP) since AMQP is a standard along the same lines as, say SMTP. There is no reason that an AMQP MOM system could not also provide a JMS library for its Java clients. SwiftMQ, for example, provides a JMS API and uses AMQP 1.0.

ActiveMQ supports AMQP v1.0 protocol clients (see http://activemq.apache.org/amqp.html for configuration help).  You can use the QPid project's JMS client or other non-JMS AQMP v1.0 clients, ActuveMQ does not currently provide it's own AMQP based JMS client.

If you are using Spring framework then you can also use Spring AMQP.
If requirement is basic and not much processing is required then you can use ActiveMQ.

It all depend on your Requirement and what type of processing you want to do with it..

Comment: You might want to load that ActiveMQ page again, it clearly states that ActiveMQ implements AMQP 1.0 as of version 5.8.0.